# while loop inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

Maybe I'm mixing apples and oranges -- $clist is a string with csv's.  I can't get $row2['$cat'] to echo anything.  Thanks in advance

```
$cats = explode(",", $clist);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
  $cat = trim($cat);
  $q = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = '$cat' ";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $link);

  $num2=mysql_num_rows($result2);

  $x = 0;
  while($x < $num2) {
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    echo $row2['$cat'];
    $x++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the quotes.  `$row2[$cat]` Otherwise, the single quotes cause literal interpretation rather than variable interpolation.

Comment: Also, the first call to `mysql_num_rows()` should be to the resource `$result`, not `$result2`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: You say "rather than", except without the quotes there is no interpolation whatsoever, as there is no string.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Clarify as _the single quotes cause literal interpretation of the string `'$cat'` instead of interpolating its variable value_

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Ah so you mean as opposed to double quotes, not as opposed to removing all quotes altogether

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, though still not sure what the expected value of `$row2[$cat]` would be since `$row2` is fetched from the query.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Yeah who the heck knows :(

Comment: @LarryLynch I recommend after you sort out the variable names `$result` vs `$result2`, if the query succeeds, fetch a row with `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` and then inspect its contents with `print_r($row);` That will help you understand what array keys it contains, as it is hard to see where you're going by putting `$cat` into the array as a key.

Answer (score 2):

From Michael Berkowski's comment: Remove the quotes. `$row2[$cat]`

Comment: Top respect for posting the answer as an answer _and_ not taking the rep credit for doing so

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a query for every value in your array, why not do a single query?

```
$cats = array('ginger','tabby','somthing');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN(\"".implode('", "',$cats)."\")";

//SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN("ginger", "tabby", "somthing")
```